# Play animation from .sks file when adding multiple reference nodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Is it possible to add the animation of a scene designed in the .sks editor when I place these nodes in my scene via:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Part\(random)Scene", ofType: "sks")
let node = SKReferenceNode(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!) as URL)
addChild(node)
```

The five or so nodes are added to the scene but are not animated as in the editor?

Thanks.

UPDATE: So, I can now get the first set to animate by ensuring they are unpaused. However when I add the same set again using the exact same code, they are still paused. The strange thing is, if I put a break point where once the nodes have been added to the scene and then just hit play when the breakpoint is reached, they start animating? Any clues as to why this is happening?

Comment: They are in a paused state

Comment: Ok. For some reason the first reference nodes I add are now animated. But if I add the same ones again they have no animation again? Any ideas?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Any ideas why adding a break point would start them animating as the update above?

Comment: Timing pause changing a change in elapsed time

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Firstly thanks for the super speedy reply! :) Any chance you could elaborate on what that means please?

Comment: When you use a break point, you are causing the system to take longer than 1/60th of a second to update.  The device needs to account for these changes, so you have things happening in the background that normally would not happen.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Ok so by adding the breakpoint I'm giving the system enough time to trigger the animation. Is there a way that I can force the system to add this animation even if it takes longer than the 1/60th of a second?

Comment: No, you are not giving it more time,  more code is firing to play catch up

Comment: @Knight0fDragon ahah alright. So can I delay some of my code to fire on the next 1/60th second so that it doesn't run out of time?

Comment: No, your issue is not time. When you are placing the break point, you are doing something your code is not expecting.  It is like trying to park a car.  Normal operation would be to apply the brake and reduce your speed until parked.  A person could also park their car by slamming into a bump, causing their car to fly, in the air, land, roll, then finally stop in a parked state.  Even though the bump got you into a parked state, it was not the expected way to do it.  You need to figure out what is going wrong and why your brake isn’t slowing you down, not finding ways to add bumps in the road.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon alright. Many many thanks for the great explanation. Not so sure how I’m gonna find what the bump that’s making my car flip is but I’ll give it a go! Cheers!

Comment: Just unpause the node after you add it to the scene

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Ok. I think I’ve tried that but will confirm and get back to you! Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Perfect all sorted. Thanks for your help! Would make as correct but not sure I can mark a comment as correct?